getting exception Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'. when scaffolind mysql EF
When scaffolding a new project to get the db from my MySql db, I get the following exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDataReaderExtension.GetValueOrDefault[T](DbDataReader reader, String name)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.GetTables(DbConnection connection, Func`3 tableFilter)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

I have installed the following version of the EF code dlls.

But when I launch the scafolding command
Scaffold-DbContext "server=192.168.1.103;port=3306;user id=root;password=root;database=test;persistsecurityinfo=True;sslmode=None" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore
I get the exception.
My database has only one test table

I have also installed the .Net Connector for mysql

Thanks for the help.

Try adding RespectBinaryFlags=false to the connectionstring see here
